# I'm trying to access socket.io in an express-generator app, but getting a null object

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I've built a web app with express generator. I'd like to be able to send updates to the browser from a number of different modules.

However, I'm not quite sure why the solution I've put together, below, doesn't work.

I know that the `exports.initialize()` function is being called, through logging to the console, but the error I'm getting, `cannot read property 'emit' of null` suggests that socket.io is *not* being initialized, because it's returning a null object.

I've created a module containing the below wrapper:

```
const sio = require('socket.io')
let io = null

exports.io = function () {
  return io
}

exports.initialize = function(server) {
  console.log("init")
  return io = sio(server)
}
```

I've initialised the module in my `app.js` file, like so:

```
// Create the http server
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

// Create the Socket IO server on
// the top of http server
const io = require('./app_modules/sockets').initialize(server)
```

and then, in modules where I need to send information to the browser, I'm calling the sockets module like this:

```
const io = require('./sockets').io()
```

Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working, and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to start a Socket.IO server, you need to invoke the Server constructor. The io constructor is only for the client side.

Your `sockets` module should look like this:

```js
const sio = require('socket.io')
let io = null

exports.io = io

exports.initialize = function(server) {
  io = new sio.Server(server);

  return io
}
```

And in modules where you need to send information to the clients, you should use something like this:

```js
const io = require('./sockets').io
```

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work either, but then I was able to get both solutions working in another module - which leads me to believe that there is a problem here that I haven't been able to identify/describe in the original question - but thank you